# Network discovery and multithreading in RMI

Tags: multithreading, rmi

I've implemented an RMI sever-client example and another program which finds out the active physical machines on the network. I've to develop an application where:
1. Server multicasts "any clients alive" to all m/c in subnet.
2. Clients respond with their current state and "alive messages"
1-2 should happen periodically
3. Server executes operations on the client machine(s) using RMI.

Can someone pls tell me how to put my programs together so that I can get my application running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you check out [Jini](http://www.jini.org), which performs the above discovery/keep-alive etc. via multicast together with the RMI invocation mechanism.